# aurelia bread crumb implementation

Tags: aurelia

all
I'm trying to implement heruan/aurelia-breadcrumbs and i'm getting this error

```
system.src.js:1056 GET 
http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/heruan/aurelia-
breadcrumbs@0.2.5/breadcrumbs.js 404 (Not Found)G @ 
system.src.js:1056(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1782e._execute @ 
bluebird.min.js:31i._resolveFromExecutor @ bluebird.min.js:32i @ 
bluebird.min.js:32(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1781(anonymous 
function) @ system.src.js:2810(anonymous function) @ 
system.src.js:3388(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3702(anonymous 
function) @ system.src.js:4094(anonymous function) @ 
system.src.js:4557(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4826(anonymous 
function) @ system.src.js:412r @ 
bluebird.min.js:33i._settlePromiseFromHandler @     
bluebird.min.js:32i._settlePromise @ 
bluebird.min.js:32i._settlePromise0 @ 
bluebird.min.js:32i._settlePromises @ bluebird.min.js:32r._drainQueue 
@ bluebird.min.js:31r._drainQueues @ bluebird.min.js:31drainQueues @ 
bluebird.min.js:31
bluebird.min.js:31 
Unhandled rejection Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found)    
loading http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/heruan/aurelia-
breadcrumbs@0.2.5/breadcrumbs.js
Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading 
http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/heruan/aurelia-
breadcrumbs@0.2.5/breadcrumbs.js
Error loading 
http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/heruan/aurelia-
breadcrumbs@0.2.5/breadcrumbs.js
```

If not this, please help out in implementing bread crumb in aurelia in any other different way using aurelia only.

Comment: Well - as the error says system.js can't find the aurelia-breadcrumb JS file. Have you installed the package correctly?

Comment: Are you using Aurelia CLI?

Answer (score 0):

It is easier if you do it on top of the skeleton app available [here](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation) click on the Download link for the latest Skeletons.